# JQuery Mobile Select box population not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectbox

I have two select boxes called crop and variety.The variety select box loaded via Ajax depends on the selection of crop and then rendered to JQueryMobile,its working when directly run that page,but incase of  redirect into that page from another page that time the variety population not working.
please help me...

my page----

```
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<?php
require_once('calendar/classes/tc_calendar.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>            
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" src="calendar/calendar.js"></script>
        <link href="calendar/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">      
        <!--<script src="jquery.js"></script>-->            
    </head>     
    <body>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#crop").change(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'GET',
                        url :'variety.php',
                        dataType:"json",                            
                        data: ({crop: $('#crop').val()}),
                        success : function(data){

                            $("#variety").html(data).selectmenu('refresh', true);                                
                        },
                        error : function(data){
                            //                        alert("Error"+data);
                        }
                    });

                });
            });
        </script>
        <script>
            function onSuccess(data, status)
            {
                data = $.trim(data);
                $("#notification").text(data);
            }

            function onError(data, status)
            {
                // handle an error
            }       

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#submit").click(function(){

                    var formData = $("#myform").serialize();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "offerReq_save.php",
                        cache: false,
                        data: formData,
                        success: onSuccess,
                        error: onError
                    });

                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>

        <?php
        session_start();
        //$_SESSION["user_id"] = 10;
        $_SESSION["type"] = $_GET['type']; //"farmer offer";
        $_SESSION["ref"] = $_GET['ref']; //"new";
        $_SESSION["ictype"] = $_GET['ictype']; //"crop";
        // $_SESSION["usertype"] = "farmer";
        $types = $_SESSION["type"];
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "itemfile");
        if (!$con) {
            die('Could not Connect:' . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("agropiamob", $con);
        $tests = mysql_query("select * from m01_crop_master"); // or die("Note: " . mysql_error());       
        mysql_close($con);
        ?>
        <section id="page1" data-role="page">               
            <header data-role="header"><h1>Header</h1></header>
            <div data-role="content" class="content">
                <form id="myform">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="type" class="select">Type :</label>
                        <select name="type" id="type" data-native-menu="false">
                            <option value="Product">Product</option>
                            <option value="Service">Service</option>
                            <option value="Bank">Bank</option>
                            <option value="Insurance">Insurance</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>                                        

                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="crop" class="select">Crop :</label>
                            <select name="crop" id="crop" data-native-menu="false"><option selected>Choose an option</option>
                                <?php
                                while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($tests)) {
                                    $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$res['id']}'>{$res['crop_name']}</option>";
                                }
                                echo $dropdown;
                                //}
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="variety" class="select">Variety :</label>
                            <select name="variety" id="variety" data-native-menu="false">
                            </select>
                        </div>                                                                     
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label id="locationLabel" for="location" class="select">Location :</label>
                        <input type="text" name="location" id="location">
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="terms" class="select">Terms :</label>
                        <select name="terms" id="terms" data-native-menu="false">
                            <option value="FOB">FOB</option>
                            <option value="CIF">CIF</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">                        
                        <!--<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox"}'>                        -->
                        <!--<label for="mydate" class="select">Date :</label>-->
                        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
                            <tr>
                                <td nowrap>Date :</td>
                                <td><?php
                    $myCalendar = new tc_calendar("mydate", true, false);
                    $myCalendar->setIcon("calendar/images/iconCalendar.gif");
                    // $myCalendar->setDate(date('d'), date('m'), date('Y'));//
                    $myCalendar->setPath("calendar/");
                    $myCalendar->setYearInterval(2000, 2015);
                    $myCalendar->dateAllow('2008-05-13', '2015-03-01');
                    $myCalendar->setDateFormat('j F Y');
                    $myCalendar->setHeight(350); //
                    //$myCalendar->autoSubmit(true, "form1");//
                    $myCalendar->setAlignment('left', 'bottom');
                    //$myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("2011-04-01", "2011-04-04", "2011-12-25"), 0, 'year');
                    //$myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("2011-04-10", "2011-04-14"), 0, 'month');
                    //$myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("2011-06-01"), 0, '');
                    $myCalendar->writeScript();
                    ?></td>
                               <!-- <td><input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Check the value" onClick="javascript:alert(this.form.mydate.value);"></td>-->
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <!--<label for="validity">Validity :</label>
                        <input name="validity" id="validity" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox"}'>-->
                        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
                            <tr>
                                <td nowrap>Validity :</td>
                                <td><?php
                                    $myCalendar = new tc_calendar("validity", true, false);
                                    $myCalendar->setIcon("calendar/images/iconCalendar.gif");
                                    // $myCalendar->setDate(date('d'), date('m'), date('Y'));//
                                    $myCalendar->setPath("calendar/");
                                    $myCalendar->setYearInterval(2000, 2015);
                                    $myCalendar->dateAllow('2008-05-13', '2015-03-01');
                                    $myCalendar->setDateFormat('j F Y');
                                    $myCalendar->setHeight(350); //
                                    //$myCalendar->autoSubmit(true, "form1");//
                                    $myCalendar->setAlignment('left', 'bottom');
                                    //$myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("2011-04-01", "2011-04-04", "2011-12-25"), 0, 'year');
                                    //$myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("2011-04-10", "2011-04-14"), 0, 'month');
                                    //$myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("2011-06-01"), 0, '');
                                    $myCalendar->writeScript();
                    ?></td>
                               <!-- <td><input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Check the value" onClick="javascript:alert(this.form.mydate.value);"></td>-->
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label id="payment_termsLabel" for="payment_terms" class="select">Payment Terms :</label>
                        <input type="text" name="payment_terms" id="payment_terms">
                    </div>                       
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="remarks">Remarks :</label>
                        <textarea name="remarks" id="remarks" cols="10" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="freq" class="select">Frequency :</label>
                        <select name="freq" id="freq" data-native-menu="false">
                            <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
                            <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
                            <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">                    
                        <button type="submit" id="submit" data-inline="true">Submit</button>
                        <button type="reset" data-inline="true">Cancel</button>
                        <h3 id="notification"></h3>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <footer data-role="footer"><h1>Footer</h1></footer>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready(function() {` <--this is your problem. When you use jQM this event fires only once. It is connected with DOM managment of this library.

Try to add event like this:

```
$('#pageId').bind('pageshow', function(){

});
```

pageId is id attribute in your `<div data-role="page" id="pageId">`.

Check this page for more events: [jQM Docs - Events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html)

Comment: I just tried as u said but that event not working.then add event like this  `$('#pageId').live('pagecreate', function(){

});` this time the page refreshed when I change the **crop** value.